# Serialize a many-to-many relationship with a single extra field with Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model where a `User` can take part in multiple `Game` and a `Game` can be played by multiple `User`. Each `User` has a `score` field in a `Game`.

To achieve this, I have followed the example provided in the Django documentation to implement such a `ManyToMany` relationship with an additional field by creating a third model `Membership` to link the `Game` table and the `User` one.

I have the following `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

# triggered as soon as a new user is saved in the db
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


class Game(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')


class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I have written `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Membership, Game


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # unique email
        model._meta.get_field('email').__dict__['_unique'] = True
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        if 'password' in validated_data:
                user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
                user.save()
        return user

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    users = UserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('users',)

class MembershipSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='game.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Membership

        fields = ('id', 'score')
```

My goal is to be able to save a new `Game` by posting something like:

```
{ 
{user_id = 1,
score = 25},
{user_id = 2,
score = 10}
}
```

I am thus wondering how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use Django generic views where you can have  CreateAPI view ,where after each game you can create an  membership object.

But you have to use a ModelSerializer instead of HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this manually as:

serializers.py

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('user ', 'game', 'score')
```

views.py

```
class GameViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Game.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    @detail_route(methods=['POST'])
    def bulk_create(self, request, pk):
        game = self.get_object()
        datas = request.data.getlist('data')
        import ast
        for _data in datas:
            data = ast.literal_eval(_data)
            data['game'] = game.id
            serializer = MembershipSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid()
                serializer.save()
            else:
                pass
        return Response('success')
```

the data you post is something like {'data':[{user_id = 1,score = 25}]}

the post url is `/game/your_game_id/bulk_create/`,
not test code,your may get some error,but you can achieve like this.